# A code trying to check one of Fermat's theories is throwing an exception

Tags: java, performance, exception

I wrote a code that needs to check if a  theory that says that the following formula can never be true unless `n=2 a^n + b^n = c^n`.
The program do tell me at the end "Meh, Fermat was right" marking the end of the program, but afterwards it throws al lot of lines of exception.

This is the code -

```
public class CheckFermats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=2;
        int b=2;
        int c=2;
        int n=3;
        int round = 2;
        CheckupA (a,b,c,n,round);

    }

    public static void CheckupA (int a, int b, int c, int n ,int round){
        if (Math.pow(a,n)+Math.pow(b,n)==Math.pow(c, n))
        {
            System.out.println("HOLYSHIT FERMET WAS WRONG!!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (a==9)
            {
                a=round+1;
                CheckupB (a,b,c,n, round);

            }
            else
            {
            a++;
            CheckupA (a,b,c,n, round);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void CheckupB (int a, int b, int c, int n,int round){
        if (Math.pow(a,n)+Math.pow(b,n)==Math.pow(c, n))
        {
            System.out.println("HOLYSHIT FERMET WAS WRONG!!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (b==9)
            {
                b=round+1;
                CheckupC (a,b,c,n, round);

            }
            else
            {
            b++;
            CheckupB (a,b,c,n, round);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void CheckupC (int a, int b, int c, int n,int round){
        if (Math.pow(a,n)+Math.pow(b,n)==Math.pow(c, n))
        {
            System.out.println("HOLYSHIT FERMET WAS WRONG!!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (c==9)
            {
                c=round+1;
                round++;
                CheckIfFinished (n);
                checkIfIncreaseN (a,b,c,round, n);
                CheckupA (a,b,c,n, round);

            }
            else
            {
            c++;
            CheckupC (a,b,c,n, round);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void checkIfIncreaseN(int a, int b, int c, int round, int n){
        if(round==9)
        {
            round = 2;
            a=2;
            b=2;
            c=2;
            n++;
            CheckupA (a,b,c,n,round);

        }
    }

    public static void CheckIfFinished (int n){
        if (n==9)
        {
            System.out.println("Meh, Fermet was right");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me guess: `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Please, if you have more than one question ask them separately. Also add the stacktrace and more information about the exception you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code goes on, even if you have checked that `Meh, Fermet was right`. See your code `CheckIfFinished (n);` even if it is finished it goes on.

So you can add a variable to the method which checks if the check was fulfilled or use the return value of the method for it.

E.g. with additional parameter:

```
public static void CheckupC (int a, int b, int c, int n,int round, boolean finished)
{
    if (finished) {return;}
    ...
}
```

Or you use the return value of the method so show that it is finished.

```
if (CheckupC(...)) { return true; }
```

When you use this for the whole code it would look like this (maybe it is not the best style but it solves your problem):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=2;
    int b=2;
    int c=2;
    int n=3;
    int round = 2;
    CheckupA (a,b,c,n,round);

}
public static boolean CheckupA (int a, int b, int c, int n ,int round)
{
    if (Math.pow(a,n)+Math.pow(b,n)==Math.pow(c, n))
    {
        System.out.println("HOLYSHIT FERMET WAS WRONG!!");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (a==9)
        {
            a=round+1;
            return CheckupB (a,b,c,n, round);

        }
        else
        {
            a++;
            return CheckupA (a,b,c,n, round);
        }
    }
}
public static boolean CheckupB (int a, int b, int c, int n,int round)
{
    if (Math.pow(a,n)+Math.pow(b,n)==Math.pow(c, n))
    {
        System.out.println("HOLYSHIT FERMET WAS WRONG!!");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (b==9)
        {
            b=round+1;
            return CheckupC (a,b,c,n, round);

        }
        else
        {
            b++;
            return CheckupB (a,b,c,n, round);
        }
    }
}
public static boolean CheckupC (int a, int b, int c, int n,int round)
{
    if (Math.pow(a,n)+Math.pow(b,n)==Math.pow(c, n))
    {
        System.out.println("HOLYSHIT FERMET WAS WRONG!!");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (c==9)
        {
            c=round+1;
            round++;
            if (CheckIfFinished (n)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (checkIfIncreaseN (a,b,c,round, n)) {
                return true;
            }
            return CheckupA (a,b,c,n, round);

        }
        else
        {
            c++;
            return CheckupC (a,b,c,n, round);
        }
    }
}
public static boolean checkIfIncreaseN(int a, int b, int c, int round, int n)
{
    if(round==9)
    {
        round = 2;
        a=2;
        b=2;
        c=2;
        n++;
        return CheckupA (a,b,c,n,round);
    }

    return false;
}
public static boolean CheckIfFinished (int n)
{
    if (n==9)
    {
        System.out.println("Meh, Fermet was right");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also some more advice when you make calculations with `double` don't compare the double values with `==` instead use `Double.compare`.

Comment: `Double.compare` won't help him solve lost precision. When dealing with Diophantine equations, the only correct way is sticking to integer arithmetics.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yep but my advice was in general for `double` calculations

Comment: Yep, the advice is off-topic (if not downright misleading).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the advise, will use it, but the thing is, I didn't reach the stage in the book where I learn return statements, so the book expects me to do it without using it.

Comment: @Tomer.A there is also the possibility instead the return value use a global static variable which you can check instead of the return value or give the same object as input to each method, set the object when the result is reached and check instead of the return value this object.